# Why is the "coefficients" from ee.Reducer.linearRegression() different from the "scale" from ee.Reducer.linearFit() in Google Earth Engine (GEE)?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get the regression coefficient in GEE, but why is the "coefficients" from ee.Reducer.linearRegression() different from the "scale" from ee.Reducer.linearFit()? Below is my code:

````
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2003, 1, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020, 1, 1);
var pointTest = ee.Geometry.Point(92.42316926660438,52.495827389391145);

var MOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A3')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate)).select(['NDVI'])
  
var snow_albedo = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate)).select('snow_albedo').map(function(image){
  return image.reproject(MOD.first().projection());
});

var combinedCollection = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.inner().apply({
  primary: MOD,
  secondary: snow_albedo,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })
}));

var NDVI_snow_albedo = combinedCollection.map(function(combined) {
  var image1 = ee.Image(combined.get('primary')); // y
  var image2 = ee.Image(combined.get('secondary')); // x
  return image2.addBands(image1); 
});

// linear regression using ee.Reducer.linearRegression()
var linearRegression_NDVI_snow_albedo = NDVI_snow_albedo.reduce(
  ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
    numX: 1,
    numY: 1
}));

// the output is 3787.1719624598018
print('coefficients max', linearRegression_NDVI_snow_albedo.select('coefficients').reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(),pointTest,1));


// linear regression using ee.Reducer.linearFit()
var linearFit_NDVI_snow_albedo = NDVI_snow_albedo.reduce( ee.Reducer.linearFit());

// the output is 8065.187449604554
print('slope: ', linearFit_NDVI_snow_albedo.select('scale').reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(),pointTest,1))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linearFit` computes slope and offset.  `linearRegression` computes as many coefficients you ask for, buy you only asked for 1, slope.  So you have no constant term, and therefore a different answer.

Comment: Thank, to get the identical answer, when getting the NDVI_snow_albedo, change 
`return image2.addBands(image1);`
to 
`var addConstantTOimage2 = ee.Image(1).addBands(image2);`
`return ee.Image(addConstantTOimage2).addBands(image1);`
Then change `numX: 1` to `numX: 2`